# ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ssh, tcp, raspberry-pi

I'm having problems connecting to my server via ssh. My client is a Arch machine, the server is a Raspberry Pi.
I get this error message:

```
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection reset by peer.
```

Any idea of what is this?

Comment: You should consider moving this question to http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/. Stackoverflow is for help writing software.

Comment: Did you find any solution ? I know it's not the right place, but it's the first showing up on google...

Comment: Someone found my password, actually it was the default one so I deserved it, and changed the password and messed some stuff.